Custom Widget for Search Bar
I am on Django 5.0.7. I wanted to define a custom widget SearchBar, which when associated with a CharField, would automatically render a text input box for search, followed by a search button. I created a template html and put it at a custom location. I tried to create a new widget by inheriting from django.forms.widgets.Input, but when I give template_name=, it tries to locate the path in django/forms/templates only, not my custom location myapp/forms/templates. It looks like this path is baked into django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates. Is there a simpler way than inheriting from DjangoTemplates then adding template paths to achieve what I want?
BTW, I use Bootstrap5, and so also use django-bootstrap5, so I suppose I need to write a renderer for this too.
Would I be better off manually rendering the field and button in every form by hand rather than define a custom widget?
Here's the code:
class SearchBar(django.forms.widgets.Input):
    input_type = 'search'
    template_name = 'widgets/search.html'

where the actual template is in myapp/forms/templates/widgets/search.html. Just for a starter, I copied code from django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/text.html to search.html. It fails with TemplateNotFound for widgets/search.html. If it had worked, I was hoping to add button html to the template.

Bootstrap might be the way to go but bear in mind you would need to add the functionality using perhaps JavaScript

Can you show how you wrote the custom Input class?

"Is there a simpler way than inheriting from DjangoTemplates then adding template paths to achieve what I want?" well it depends what you want to do. So perhaps by providing the widget and the template, it probably makes it easier to help you.

class SearchBar(django.forms.Input): input_type = 'search'  template_name = 'widgets/search.html' where the actual template is in myapp/forms/templates/widgets/search.html. Just for a starter, I copied code of django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/text.html to search.html. It fails with TemplateNotFound for widgets/search.html. If it had worked, I was hoping to add button html to the template.

Did you enable the APP_DIRS setting for the templates?

This is in my settings.py: TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'], 'APP_DIRS': True, ...}].


where the actual template is in myapp/forms/templates/widgets/search.html.

That means Django will not find it, you locate this under:
myapp/templates/widgets/search.html
so without the forms/.

Worked, thanks so much!!! So the field rendering also adds the standard app templates directory to the template path... I dug into the code, but didn't come across this code, maybe I didn't study it well enough.

@fishfin To help persons who might have this question in the future, accept as answer if this answers your question.
